# Problem booting Ubuntu from newer Macbook Pro (late 2011 model)

Tags: startup, unix, efi

I'm trying to create a USB stick that is bootable on both PC and Intel Mac systems, which will contain a full installation of Ubuntu (i.e. not just a LiveCD).

I've succeeded in creating a USB that will boot on PCs and a Macbook Pro from ~2009. However, trying the same USB on a newer Macbook Pro, from late 2011, does not work.

I have gone with a method adapted from the one described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1065670), which creates a Mac partition on the USB and copies some rEFIt files into it.

On booting the new Macbook Pro, holding the option key allows the choice of boot device to be made. Selecting rEFIt then allows Linux to be chosen, which works the same way as on the older Macbook Pro. However, on the late 2011 model, following the selection of Linux, all I get is a screen saying that no bootable devices were found.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and, if so, how to fix it? The version of Ubuntu I am trying to run is 10.04 32-bit.

Comment: Not sure if this will resolve your issue, but why are you not booting a more recent version of Ubuntu? 10.04 would be more than a year older than your MBP itself.

Comment: I had considered that. At the moment, I'm simply using 10.04 because I don't like the interface of the newer versions of Ubuntu.

I wouldn't have thought that the OS would make much difference, however, as it isn't getting that far. The Mac simply doesn't recognise a bootable partition on the USB. I may be wrong, but the only difference I can think of is if the version of GRUB that is packaged with newer versions of Ubuntu have better compatibility with Macs.

Comment: I have the same problem with my early 2011 MacBook Pro and am looking for an answer as well..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using a DVD with the image burned onto it instead of a USB drive. (USB images never seem to work.)

Also rEFIt is still fine for use as the bootloader. Old question, I know, but it might help.